# Beginner: How can I end this while loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program where if the user enters 'q' or 'quit' or 'Quit' the loop will break. I figured out how to do half of the problem but I've been stuck for over an hour with the rest.

```
text = ()
while text != 'q' or 'quit' or 'Quit':
    print((text)[::-1])
    text = input()
```

The code above won't end the loop when typing any of the keywords, but if i do only:
`while text != 'q'` that works. How can I add the other two?
Thank you.

Comment: See that link on why your "multiple" attempt didn't work. Also, you need `and`, not `or`. You want to ensure that they *all* hold, not that any one of them is true. You could also reconfigure it using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `in` as in the following :

```
text = ()
while text not in ('q', 'quit', 'Quit'):
    print((text)[::-1])
    text = input()
```

Comment: Why move the check out of the `while` statement?

Comment: I honestly find it more readable this way but sure